# Application icon does not show up in Full HD device

Tags: android, icons, android-image

I have written the very basic code to run an android application

> **AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.examples.sampleapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.examples.sampleapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

> **Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

**The drawable folder under *res***

[image]

This is the result I get on a device

**DEVICE 1**

[XOLO Q700](http://www.gsmarena.com/xolo_q700-5534.php) with resolution of 540 x 960 pixels, 4.5 inches (~245 ppi pixel density)

[image]

The app icon shows up as expected on this device.

The same app when I run on

**Device 2**

[Lenovo K900](http://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_k900-5241.php) with resolution of 1080 x 1920 pixels, 5.5 inches (~401 ppi pixel density) I get a screen like this

[image]

**The app icon is missing from the second device screen shot**

What is that is missing to be added?

Please tell what more information is needed to find out the reason...I will post them.

Comment: This may sound crazy, but try creating a "dummy" icon called aaaaa.png in each of your drawable folders.

Comment: Crazy!!! Yes...It had no effect...Even tried changing the name of the icon and adding it in the manifest....still no luck....

Comment: Worth a shot, I had an app before that wouldn't detect the first image in my drawable folders, so I had to add a "dummy" image that acted as the image that got looked over. Apparently it is a bug in Android so thought it might be worth a shot :P

Comment: What happens if you add a "drawable" folder with the icon in it?  It could be that the device is meeting none of those qualifiers.

Comment: @Enragedmrt Well, I tried that also but no effect I have updated the res folder in the question also added the -xxxhdpi folder , and I  also tried it with the aaaaa.png

Answer (score 0):

Did u resolve this? I had the same issue, problem was I had the default android icon saved under drawable/large and drawable/xxhdpi and my own customised icon saved under drawable/hdpi, all files sharing the same name - ic_launger.png. Pasting over the default android icons did the job.